# Trying to Root my phone

Tags: rooting, root-access

I have a Samsung on7 phone which works on android 6.0.1 marshmallow. I want to root my phone but I'm not able to root my phone with any third party software. I always get the error message "root permission acquiring unsuccessful." Is there any other way I could root my phone?

Comment: Could you add more details about your phone (exact model...)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install a suitable and supported custom recovery on your phone then try flashing the popular SuperSU's zip.. this would successfully root your device... (this worked on my Samsung J2 Pro '16 edition)

Comment: Could u send me the links? Coz i dont know much abt cutom recovery and thngs like that

Comment: Kingroot is also good

Answer (score 0):

To root your device first you need to install a particular custom recovery for your device like **TWRP** . then only you can root your device running on marshmallow.

Comment: Isn't CWM better for Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

U can look at cf auto root website just type it in to google the scroll to down to Odin flash able list and find your model download that and then.  look up how to root your phone with cf auto root and Odin you didn't say the if it was a edge or standard s7 and what carrier you have so I can't post a link but prosess is very very simple